# Exchange 2010. Server name keeps defaulting to domain.local vs web address

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-2010

under Account settings/Server on office 2010 (exchange 2010 as well) its defaulting to system.domain.local instead of the web address for our exchange server. This is causing connectivity issues when people are out of the office and off our internal network. 
You can manually change the server from the .local to the external web address but it changes itself back.

Do you know where this setting would be to change it so the default is always the web address? For the internal network we have an internal DNS rule that will connect them to the server if they are here so there wouldnt be any issue if it never defaulted back to .local.

Main exchange server's OS is server 2008 ent R2

Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

Either set up VPN connections for your users, or activate [RPC over HTTP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-outlook-anywhere-to-connect-to-your-exchange-server-without-vpn-HP010102444.aspx) (dubbed 'Outlook Anywhere')

Comment: For security reasons only a select few have access to VPN. Most users can connect externally without a problem but i'm showing a couple that are having this major issue. Outlook anywhere is enabled and setup correctly. What I would like to see into doing is changing the default internal domain to our external mail server URL (mail.example.com) instead of having it default to the system.domain.local address. Whenever its changed manually it reverts back.

Comment: I only have Exchange 2007 available to check, but in the RPC configuration you have to specify both an internal and external address. These settings get pushed to the Outlook clients.
Did this recently on an otherwise standard config and worked without further configuration.

Comment: Hey j0risvdb thanks for the advice! Outlook anywhere (RPC over HTTP) is set correctly and has the external domain. I'm trying to remove the "internal network" functionality. I want it to always populate with the mail.externaldomain.com vs the servername.domainname.local. I'm totally lost here. I've been searching the past few days with no luck